# Could not find configuration node: reporting/dataProvider

Tags: weblog

We are suddenly getting this error message on our Sitecore CD instances. It is only affecting one portion of the website, Blog. We use WeBlog module to manage blog content. Content editors claims they didn't do anything. No new code deployments were done either.

The same content is rendering fine in CM. Let me know if you need more info and I will provide. Thank you in advance!

---

```
Could not find configuration node: reporting/dataProvider
Description: An unhandled exception occurred.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find configuration node: reporting/dataProvider

Source Error:


Line 16:         </main>
Line 17:         <aside class="wb-rightcolumn">
Line 18:             @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("weblog-sidebar")
Line 19:         </aside>
Line 20:         <footer id="bottom">

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Views\WeBlog\Blog.cshtml    Line: 18

Stack Trace:


[InvalidOperationException: Could not find configuration node: reporting/dataProvider]
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConfigNode(String xpath, Boolean assert) +543
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +187
   Sitecore.Xdb.Reporting.ReportingQueryBase..ctor(ReportDataProviderBase reportProvider, CachingPolicy cachingPolicy) +40
   Sitecore.Xdb.Reporting.ItemBasedReportingQuery..ctor(ID queryItemId, ReportDataProviderBase reportProvider, CachingPolicy cachingPolicy) +26
   Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Analytics.Reporting.ItemVisitsQuery..ctor(ReportDataProviderBase reportProvider) +95
   Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Managers.EntryManager.GetItemViews(ID itemId) +90
   Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Managers.EntryManager.<GetPopularEntriesByView>b__21_0(Entry x) +113
   System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.ComputeKeys(TElement[] elements, Int32 count) +108
   System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count) +29
   System.Linq.<GetEnumerator>d__1.MoveNext() +185
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +127
   System.Linq.<TakeIterator>d__25`1.MoveNext() +185
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +453
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +69
   Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Managers.EntryManager.GetPopularEntriesByView(Item blogItem, Int32 maxCount) +559
   Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Components.InterestingEntriesCore.GetEntries(Item blogItem, Int32 maxCount) +272
   Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Mvc.Model.InterestingEntries.Initialize(Rendering rendering) +157
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter) +161
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.GetModel() +316
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.get_Model() +31
   Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions.ObjectExtensions.ValueOrDefault(T source, Func`2 resultGetter) +51
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.get_Model() +163
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +160

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/Views/WeBlog/InterestingEntries.cshtml'.
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +735
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +74
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +192
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer) +250
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +61
   ASP._Page_Views_WeBlog_Blog_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Views\WeBlog\Blog.cshtml:18
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +263

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/Views/WeBlog/Blog.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Mvc.Model.Blog, Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +735
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +74
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +192
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer) +250
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +61
   ASP._Page_Views_WeBlog_MvcLayout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Views\WeBlog\MvcLayout.cshtml:18
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +263

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/Views/WeBlog/MvcLayout.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +735
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +74
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +297
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +378
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +91
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +795
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +795
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
```

Comment: Error messages/stack traces needs to be in the post as text, not images. SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Your `InterestingEntries` component on CD server is supposed to display popular entries from your website.

In order to do that, it's trying to use Reporting database to get `PopularEntriesByView` using `ItemVisitsQuery`.

On your CD server, `reporting/dataProvider` part of configuration is missing.

With that said, this component cannot be rendered with your existing CD server configuration. So either it never worked on CD server or configuration of your CD server was changed since it worked last time.

You may try to find in your config files `<reporting` section and make sure that it's also applied on CD servers (either add `ContentDelivery` role if you use role based configuration or copy files if you're on some older version of Sitecore) but there is a chance that some of Sitecore reporting dlls are also missing.